# split the text for a fixed length considering the delimiter

Tags: r, tidyverse

split the text for a fixed length of 200 considering the delimiter, in this example consider the delimiter as space. here is the sample data , where i would like to derive `col, col1, col2` based on
`text` variable

```r
df <- data.frame(id=1,text='The INDEXC function searches source from left to right, for the first occurrence of any character present in the 
excerpts and returns the position in source of that character. If none of the characters in excerpt-1 through excerpt-n 
in source are found, INDEXC returns a value of 0. The REVERSE function creates backward writing, such that the 
last character in the argument becomes the first character in the result, the next-to-last character in the argument 
becomes the second character in the result, and so on. Below macro combines INDEXC/REVERSE function to
automatically derive COVAL-COVALn based on comment’s length.',
                 col='The INDEXC function searches source from left to right, for the first occurrence of any character present in the 
excerpts and returns the position in source of that character. If none of the characters in excerpt-1 through excerpt-n ',
                 col1='in source are found, INDEXC returns a value of 0. The REVERSE function creates backward writing, such that the 
last character in the argument becomes the first character in the result, the next-to-last character in the argument 
becomes',
col2='the second character in the result, and so on. Below macro combines INDEXC/REVERSE function to
automatically derive COVAL-COVALn based on comment’s length.')
```

Comment: Is this a question or an AI prompt?

Comment: it is a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` and `stringi`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

df <- data.frame(id = 1, text = "The INDEXC function searches source from left to right, for the first occurrence of any character present in the excerpts and returns the position in source of that character. If none of the characters in excerpt-1 through excerpt-n in source are found, INDEXC returns a value of 0. The REVERSE function creates backward writing, such that the last character in the argument becomes the first character in the result, the next-to-last character in the argument becomes the second character in the result, and so on. Below macro combines INDEXC/REVERSE function to automatically derive COVAL-COVALn based on comment's length.")
setDT(df)
matches <- unlist(stri_match_all_regex(df$text, ".{1,220}(?=\\b)"))
cols <- sprintf("col%s", seq_along(matches))
df[, (cols) := as.list(matches)]
df

  id
1:  1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               text
1: The INDEXC function searches source from left to right, for the first occurrence of any character present in the excerpts and returns the position in source of that character. If none of the characters in excerpt-1 through excerpt-n in source are found, INDEXC returns a value of 0. The REVERSE function creates backward writing, such that the last character in the argument becomes the first character in the result, the next-to-last character in the argument becomes the second character in the result, and so on. Below macro combines INDEXC/REVERSE function to automatically derive COVAL-COVALn based on comment's length.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      col1
1: The INDEXC function searches source from left to right, for the first occurrence of any character present in the excerpts and returns the position in source of that character. If none of the characters in excerpt-1 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           col2
1: through excerpt-n in source are found, INDEXC returns a value of 0. The REVERSE function creates backward writing, such that the last character in the argument becomes the first character in the result, the next-to-last 
                                                                                                                                                                                           col3
1: character in the argument becomes the second character in the result, and so on. Below macro combines INDEXC/REVERSE function to automatically derive COVAL-COVALn based on comment's length
```